# Different speed for Magic Mouse and built-in trackpad

Tags: mouse, trackpad

Is there any way to set different tracking speed for Magic Mouse and for built-in trackpad?

I'm using both, but Magic Mouse acts good for me at max tracking speed, but trackpad good for me at average tracking speed.

I see that tracking speeds are adjusted separately for each input device, but actually they affect both mouse and trackpad.

Is there any chance to set different configurations?

MacOs Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 2):

In my testing just now, the trackpad and mouse have separate tracking speeds. I moved the trackpad to the slowest setting, and the mouse to the fastest. The trackpad was slow and the mouse was fast. The two did not seem to affect each other.

The answer should be to move each to the setting that works for you.

Could you elaborate more on what happens when your adjustments affect each other? Have you tried setting each to a different extreme to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like USB Overdrive to have the system setting for acceleration for one device and then see if you can skip that device in USB Overdrive. Then use overdrive to set a different (faster or slower) acceleration than the default.

- http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Step.html

There are a lot of other modifiers like Better Touch Tool that many people love and use - but I don’t think any of the others have this differential speed setting that seems a natural thing to want. I move my fingers on the trackpad very small motion and move my hand in large motion on the mouse naturally.